# using "return Content" in Webmatrix

Tags: razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

Does anyone know how i would write the following in WebMatrix ASP.Net Web Pages?

```
return Content(Constants.Gateway.WebhookNotification.Verify(Request.QueryString["bt_challenge"]));
```

I think the return Content method is used by MVC only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the result of the expression, but you can render it to the browser like this:

```
@Constants.Gateway.WebhookNotification.Verify(Request.QueryString["bt_challenge"]))
```

Or you can store it in a variable:

```
var myVar = Constants.Gateway.WebhookNotification.Verify(Request.QueryString["bt_challenge"]));
```

Comment: I've tried rendering in the browser, which is what i want to do, but i'm getting the error "String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s"

Comment: That looks like an error being raised somewhere in the method you are calling. Perhaps your query string value doesn't exist? You should look at whatever documentation you have for the Gateway API.

Comment: Yeah, the API documentation is written for MVC, so I've been trying to re-engineer that code, and it's proving difficult :p